# global alignment sequence function

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, bioinformatics, sequence-alignment

I'm trying to implement [the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) to get the minimum score in the global alignment function, but instead of getting the minimum score of 0 when both the sequences are equal I get 8.

What is the problem with this code?

```
alphabet = ["A", "C", "G", "T"] 
score = [[0, 4, 2, 4, 8], \
     [4, 0, 4, 2, 8], \
     [2, 4, 0, 4, 8], \
     [4, 2, 4, 0, 8], \
     [8, 8, 8, 8, 8]]

def globalAlignment(x, y):
#Dynamic version very fast
    D = []
    for i in range(len(x)+1):
        D.append([0]* (len(y)+1))

    for i in range(1, len(x)+1):
        D[i][0] = D[i-1][0] + score[alphabet.index(x[i-1])][-1]
    for i in range(len(y)+1):
        D[0][i] = D[0][i-1]+ score[-1][alphabet.index(y[i-1])]

    for i in range(1, len(x)+1):
        for j in range(1, len(y)+1):
            distHor = D[i][j-1]+ score[-1][alphabet.index(y[j-1])]
            distVer = D[i-1][j]+ score[-1][alphabet.index(x[i-1])]
            if x[i-1] == y[j-1]:
                distDiag = D[i-1][j-1]
            else:
                distDiag = D[i-1][j-1] + score[alphabet.index(x[i-1])][alphabet.index(y[j-1])]

            D[i][j] = min(distHor, distVer, distDiag)

    return D[-1][-1]

x = "ACGTGATGCTAGCAT"
y = "ACGTGATGCTAGCAT"
print(globalAlignment(x, y))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: Specifically, you have failed to "make it easy for others to help you".  You have some sort of "magic" distance computation, which you are still hiding from us.  One-letter variable names, sequences of eye-straining subscripts -- with no documentation, explanation, or debugging trace.  *Why* do you expect 0 from these computations?  *How* did it get to `8` instead?  What are the intermediate steps that failed?

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: I've got this code from the course of Algorithms of DNA sequencing brought to us by Ben Langmead in coursera. the code ran normally in his machine but I can't get the same result in my own machine.

Answer (score 1):

**just change ->** `for i in range(len(y)+1):`  **to**  `for i in range(1, len(y) + 1):`
**and ->** `distVer = D[i-1][j]+ score[-1][alphabet.index(x[i-1])]` **to**

```
distVer = D[i - 1][j] + score[alphabet.index(x[i - 1])][-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

At least

```
distHor = D[i][j-1]+ score[-1][alphabet.index(y[j-1])]
distVer = D[i-1][j]+ score[-1][alphabet.index(x[i-1])]
```

is suspect, as you didn't use the same place for the [-1] in the initialisations,
and both distances are not likely to use the same direction in the weights...
I guess it should be

```
score[alphabet.index(x[i-1])][-1]
```

but it may not be the only error...

Comment: Hi, I fixed the problem by putting 0 instead of 8 in the last list of socre
score = [[0, 4, 2, 4, 8], \
     [4, 0, 4, 2, 8], \
     [2, 4, 0, 4, 8], \
     [4, 2, 4, 0, 8], \
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by putting 0 instead of 8 in the last list of score;

```
alphabet = ["A", "C", "G", "T"] 
score = [[0, 4, 2, 4, 8], \
     [4, 0, 4, 2, 8], \
     [2, 4, 0, 4, 8], \
     [4, 2, 4, 0, 8], \
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

def globalAlignment(x, y):
#Dynamic version very fast
D = []
for i in range(len(x)+1):
    D.append([0]* (len(y)+1))

for i in range(1, len(x)+1):
    D[i][0] = D[i-1][0] + score[alphabet.index(x[i-1])][-1]
for i in range(len(y)+1):
    D[0][i] = D[0][i-1]+ score[-1][alphabet.index(y[i-1])]

for i in range(1, len(x)+1):
    for j in range(1, len(y)+1):
        distHor = D[i][j-1]+ score[-1][alphabet.index(y[j-1])]
        distVer = D[i-1][j]+ score[alphabet.index(x[i-1])][-1]
        if x[i-1] == y[j-1]:
            distDiag = D[i-1][j-1]
        else:
            distDiag = D[i-1][j-1] + score[alphabet.index(x[i-1])][alphabet.index(y[j-1])]

        D[i][j] = min(distHor, distVer, distDiag)

return D[-1][-1]
```